# How can I get the count for how many rows were "rolled up" to be included in each GroupBy'd row (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

I have this query:

```
SELECT TOP 8 M.membername, 
             P.MemberNo
FROM   prosql05.bidata.dbo.priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN prosql05.cpsdata.dbo.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
ORDER  BY invoicedate
```

...that gives me data results such as:

[image]

And I've got this query:

```
SELECT TOP 8 M.membername, 
             P.MemberNo
FROM   dbo.priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN cpsdata.dbo.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
and unit = 'FOODBUY'
GROUP BY M.membername, P.Memberno
order by m.membername
```

...that groups the membernames together, so that I get:

[image]

What I need is a count of how many rows are represented within each grouped row; IOW, for the data above, I need to see:

```
MemberName  MemberNo    Count
----------  --------    -----
Freedom Fresh   110     1
FSA Loveland    028     3
```

How can I get that?

Comment: well...I mean, it seems that you just need to use `COUNT`?, `SELECT M.membername, P.MemberNo, COUNT(*) as [Count] ......`

Comment: `invoicedate` and `Unit` column belongs to which table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Count` Aggregate in `Select`

```
select MemberName, MemberNo, count(1) as [Count]
From 
(
--your existing query without Group by
) A
Group by MemberName, MemberNo
```

Perhaps it can be simplified like this

```
SELECT TOP 8 M.membername, 
             M.MemberNo,
             Count(1) as [Count]
FROM   dbo.priceexceptionhistorycsr P 
       JOIN cpsdata.dbo.members M 
         ON P.memberno = M.memberno 
WHERE  invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-09-04' AND '2016-09-10' 
and unit = 'FOODBUY'
GROUP BY M.membername, M.Memberno
order by m.membername
```

Further to improve the performance we can add a Non Clustered Index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_members_invoicedate_unit 
    ON cpsdata.dbo.members (invoicedate,unit) include (membername,MemberNo)
```

Above `Index` considers `invoicedate`,`unit` columns are from `cpsdata.dbo.members` table. If no, Please clarify to make required changes

Comment: 500rep for a missing `count()`, that's very well paid ;-) Though your answer is nice because you are expanding

Comment: @ThomasG - Even am shocked after seeing bounty ;)